# How can I run uniswap app interface on my local?

Tags: uniswap, npm, typescript

For a few days, I have been trying to run uniswap v3 app interface(https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap) on my local.

Reference url : https://github.com/ChainSafe/uniswap-frontend

https://github.com/Uniswap/interface

But I faced this same error.

```
>npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @uniswap/interface@undefined
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   dev react@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.8.0" from @reach/dialog@0.10.5
npm ERR! node_modules/@reach/dialog
npm ERR!   dev @reach/dialog@"^0.10.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

It would be appreciated if anyone could fix this problem.
Thanks.

Comment: What node version are you using? Can you show more of the log? the posted isn't enough to find what is failing.

Comment: node version is v14.15.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Yarn, it helped me. If not check if you have the correct node version.